# Fetching guild's banned users

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have added `banlist` command on my Discord Bot. However, the code below only shows the size of the banned members and not the names of the banned users. I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

```
message.guild.fetchBans()
   .then(banned => {
   let list = banned.map(user => user.tag).join('\n');

      if (list.length >= 1950) list = `${list.slice(0, 1948)}...`;

   message.channel.send(`**${banned.size} users are banned:**\n${list}`);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, and by the way I updated the code. Only the number of users that are banned in the server returns.

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: I’m currently using v12.

Answer (score 2):

the collection isn't of users, its of BanInfo, which contains a .reason property

```js
message.guild.fetchBans()
    .then(banned => {
        let list = banned.map(ban => ban.user.tag).join('\n');

        if (list.length >= 1950) list = `${list.slice(0, 1948)}...`;

        message.channel.send(`**${banned.size} users are banned:**\n${list}`);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```